# Azure OAuth flow drops cookies while redirected to the client app

Tags: azure, cookies, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jetty-9

I'm trying to use azure oauth flow to get access to another tenant's data through Microsoft API

When user grants the consent and Microsoft returns back me with the auth code.
But some times (not all the time) the request from the browser to the configured redirect URL drops the cookies. I need one of the cookie for authentication purposes.

Problem in action :

1. I'm already in browser logged to my application - I can see the cookie "userseesion" set in browser
2. I click the authorize button from the app and redirected to microsoft consent page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?....redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Fresponse...)
3. Accept the consent and microsft send the auth code to "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Fresponse"
4. The problem is http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Fresponse is not receiving the cookie "userseesion", So i am again redirected to login page of my application

Comment: Please let us know which sample/document you are referring to?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?

Comment: Yes, but I did some investigation and found some more information,
1. Chrome is preventing such cookie submission when go through thirdparty redirects (recent security improvement they are doing - but still I'm confuced why its working fine time to time)
2. Some documentation explained to set the SameSite attribute as Lax "SameSite=Lax" when setting the cookie - I cannot find how to do it in jetty 9.4.22
3. This is really not a problem in Edge and Firefox, but I believe they will also include this security limitation in there future updates

Comment: Updated the tags. As you are using a jetty it would be  better someone from jetty community can answer